# Close Camera after x Seconds in Ionic 2 Application

Tags: cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am developing a cross platform application using Ionic 2 / Cordova. Where the cordova-plugin-camera plug in is being used.

The problem is that I have to close the camera from the application after x seconds.

A whole lot of reading and search has not produced any results.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't think that that's possible since the cordova app doesn't have control over the native functionality of the camera once it is open.

Comment: Do you have any idea if it is written in native (Android Studio / XCode) it would be possible? Because this is an important functionality of the App,